# Finding exact patterns with AWK

Tags: awk

I am having problems looking for an exact pattern. I have a file with this information:

```
GAT CCA AAA CAC ATT CTC CCT GGT AGC ATG GAC AAG CAA CAT TTT GGG AGA AAT GGA GCA AAA AAA CAT 
AAA CTT CAC AGT AAC AAA CAT AAA CAC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC 
TCT CTC TCT CCA CAC ACA CAC ACA CTC GCA CTC ACA GCC TCA CAA CAC AGG TAT ACA TGT TTA CTT AGG
```

and I am trying to count, for example, the number of times that GAT shows up, with AWK:

```
awk -F " " '/AAC/ {++i} END {print "Count of TC is "i"."}'
```

It gives me an incorrect, higher value than the correct one. I've tried as well doing:

```
awk -F " " '/^AAC$/ {++i} END {print "Count of TC is "i"."}'
```

but it gives me nothing or, in other words: "Count of TC is ."

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test every field with a loop, or divide it using Record Selector, then count.

Try this `gnu awk`

```
awk '/ACA/ {a++} END {print a}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file
4
```

```
awk '/AAA/ {a++} END {print a}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file
6
```

---

A `awk` loop version

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/AAA/) a++} END {print a}' file
6
```

---

Another way to do it:

```
awk '{a+=gsub(/AAA/,x)} END {print a}' file
6
```

Comment: `RS=" "` is wrong, it won't find the pattern at the end of any lines except the last one, for example. You need `RS='[[:space:]]+'` for what you're trying to do but then the solution is specific to awks that allow multi-char RSs, e.g. gawk. And the variable RS contains the Record Separator, not a Record Selector.